# Unable to insert data frame into database table of snowflake

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**I want to insert a data frame into my `Snowflake` database using the `to_sql()` method**.

This is how I am trying to do it -

```
    dataframe.to_sql(table_name, engine, index=False, method=pd_writer, if_exists="append")
```

This is what my data frame looks like -

```
    event_id                  event_timestamp event_type user_name       client_ip  ... related_event_id instance_id user_id event company_id
0  1298203705 2020-11-05 10:47:43.981000+00:00      LOGIN  SHIVKANT  52.149.162.195  ...                0           2       4     1          1
1  1298207325 2020-11-10 10:31:00.263000+00:00      LOGIN  SHIVKANT  40.118.225.132  ...                0           2       4     1          1
```

The `to_sql()` method's argument `if_exists` creates a new table if the table with the provided name does not exist.

**When I run the code stated above this is what it prints on the terminal** -

```
CREATE TABLE login_history (
        event_id BIGINT, 
        event_timestamp TIMESTAMP, 
        event_type TEXT, 
        user_name TEXT, 
        client_ip TEXT, 
        reported_client_type TEXT, 
        reported_client_version TEXT, 
        first_authentication_factor TEXT, 
        second_authentication_factor TEXT, 
        is_success TEXT, 
        error_code FLOAT, 
        error_message TEXT, 
        related_event_id BIGINT, 
        instance_id BIGINT, 
        user_id BIGINT, 
        event BIGINT, 
        company_id BIGINT
)
```

1. The table being created does not have the `primary_key` field but I want it to have a `Auto Increment`, `Primary Key` field called `id`.
2. The above code does create a table but it returns an error while inserting the data into the table.

```
    snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 000904 (42000): 0198a74a-0b5e-4dd5-0000-d5e5000a40f6: 

SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 88
    invalid identifier '"event_id"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your second error the problem may be a quoting-issue. Adding `" "` around your column-names should help here.

Comment: Tables are being created by pandas `to_sql()` method. I am not creating any table.

Comment: Yes and probably this method is creating the table with " " around the column names. --> This means you also have to reference the columns with " ".